# PHP output: file include vs. function (performance)

Tags: php, html, performance, include

Here's two methods to display html output: **function** vs **include**.  Is there a performance hit when accessing the file system as opposed to accessing memory?  If each page load has dozens, or even hundreds of includes, at what point does this become a problem?

Option 1:  Html display loop using a **function**

```
foreach ($items as $item){
    displayItem($item);
}

function displayItem($item){ ?>
    <html output>
<?php }
```

Option 2:  Html display loop using **include**

```
foreach ($items as $item){
    include $path . 'displayItem.php';
}

//inside displayItem.php:
<html output>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6451732/362536

Comment: The most sure way is to test it yourself on your setup. Though, filesystem is usually cached in memory, so it's the performance of `include` mechanism itself that matters, rather than FS performance.

Comment: In general, the performance bottleneck of a PHP site is not in the includes. Some libraries have hundreds of includes and are used in very high traffic sites. You should organise the code in your site in order to structure it correctly, rather than focusing on the speed. If you're worried about the performance of your site, run a profiler and find our what the real bottlenecks are in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, disk access is much slower than memory access, that's why disk accesses are usually cached in memory by the operating system. Even so, if you could somehow cache the output of `displayItem()` (which could include a file) then save and load the cached output from memory with something like [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php), you should see significant increases in performance.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't want to cache the output of displayItem, because it would be different for each $item.  I'm wondering if this is an acceptable format for creating ALL my (dynamic) output code.  For example, I could then use the file explorer to view all my displaySmallList vs displaySmallListNoImage, and all other variations.  I could organize them in folders.  The number of includes would be very high.  

The question is, is the file accessed once, and like a function, stored in memory, and not accessed again by the file system?  I'll have to read Brad's link when I have more time...

Comment: @MikeLewis, sure you can, you could make a cache for each item or even a cache for each page. This is a pretty common practice. But for accessing files, it depends on the filesystem, the OS, the available memory and the physical HDD (which also does some caching of its own). Alternatively, you can store everything in a ramdisk if the information can be re-generated. But if you have many items, depending on how many you display on a page vs. the total number, it's likely better to read each item from an individual file than to load *everything* in memory at once for each request.

Comment: @MikeLewis, as you can see, there are many variables here, so it's always best to benchmark if you can, since your situation may be different from someone else's. I did actually have a situation once when disk reads were the bottleneck, but it's uncommon. I recommend taking a look at [xhprof](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) or [xdebug](http://xdebug.org) which both can generate very nice and useful profiling data.